# PHP Optional Dynamic Functions Arguments

Tags: php

How we can define a dynamic function with 2 or 3 arguments. For example, if we have a function like this:

```
function required($value, $fieldname){};
```

and another function like:

```
function min($value, $fieldname, $min){};
```

and they are both dynamic so we don't know which one will be called, how we can define a dynamic method to handle both situations! We can use if else like this:

```
if(isset($min))
{
  return $functionName($value, $fieldname, $min);
} else {
  return $functionName($value, $fieldname);
}
```

But is there another way in PHP to handle this? (without using conditions)

Comment: `function required( $value = null, $fieldname = null, $min = null ){};`

Comment: is it enough? Because I don need any third argument in required function?

Comment: @Blinkydamo is correct, but I would only give the last argument a default value since the function probably doesn't make with no arguments.

Comment: @bassxzero very true.  Adding the null just mean that if nothing is passed ignore it, in simply terms.

Comment: If you can change function definition a bit, you can pass parameters as an array. So, it will always be single argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option one is to set the optional paraments to null:

```
function required( $value, $fieldname, $min = null ){};
```

As also stated you could alter your function a little and pass an array

```
$array = array( 'value' => 'value', 'min' => 'min' );
function required( $array );
```

Then inside your function:

```
extract( $array );
if( isset( $value ) ) 
{
  // Process
}
```

Repeat for all expected parameters.